# how can i delete certain words and numbers from a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a script that takes the titles of the series, but in each title there is a year and "onlajn sa prevodom".  The year varies according to the series.  How can I remove the year and "onlajn sa prevodom" using python

```
naslov = "Tajkun (2020) onlajn sa prevodom"
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Use `naslov.split()[0]` .

Comment: `naslov.partition(' ')[0]`

Comment: @MayankPorwal and dawg, this does not work in the general case, as the title can be multiple words. The expected output is `"Tajkun"`, and it would be `"Avengers: the Endgame"` if the source string was `"Avengers: the Endgame (2019) onlajn sa prevodom"`. (Yes, OP could have provided better examples, but the description of the problem was fairly precise.)

Comment: @Amadan You can split on parentheses `(`. Use this: `naslov.split('(')[0]`

Comment: @MayankPorwal `"(500) Days of Summer (2009) onlajn sa prevodom"`.

Comment: @Amadan Not sure if this is how OP is generating his string. Let him come back or close this question.

Comment: What is the general layout of the line that requires cutting? If it never uses any parentheses, then the given answers will work just fine. In case this is not true, you will probably get into the regime of using regular expressions.

Comment: @MayankPorwal OP is likely not "generating his string". He has strings containing *titles of series* where he wants to *remove the year and "onlajn sa prevodom"*. If a series with a title containing a parentheses comes to him as input tomorrow, your solution will break, as it doesn't *remove the year and "onlajn sa prevodom"* as the OP wanted, but removes the first open parenthesis and anything after it, which accidentally gives the correct answer if you're lucky to never get an input where the two differ. There's no reason to close the question, the question is very clear.

Comment: @Amadan I agree with you. Let's wait for OP to comeback. If his input string is as simple as what he shared in the question, he does not need a regex, a split would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

naslov = "Tajkun (2020) onlajn sa prevodom"

re.sub("\([0-9]{4}\) onlajn sa prevodom", "", naslov)
```

More about the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your expectation well, this might be what you are looking for,

```
naslov = "Tajkun (2020) onlajn sa prevodom"
print(naslov[:naslov.find('(')].strip())

Tajkun
```

This only works if every line contains `'()'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular experessions. This is what they are designed for.

```
import re
title = "Tajkun (2020) onlajn sa prevodom"
corrected_title = re.sub(r"\s*\(\d+\) onlajn sa prevodom", "", title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is regex matching. If you are pretty sure the string will contain this "(year) onlajn sa prevodom" pattern, you can write it in regex as

`pattern = r"\s\([0-9]+\) onlajn sa prevodom"`
Step by step:

`\s` means white space

`\([0-9]+\)` means match one or more numbers in between two parentheses.

the trailing " onlajn sa prevodom" is just used to match, to make sure the number between (xxxx) is followed by the phrase. in full here is a short program to match your example

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    expr = r"\s\([0-9]+\) onlajn sa prevodom"
    naslov1 = "Tajkun (2020) onlajn sa prevodom"
    naslov2 = "Tajkun (2019) onlajn sa prevodom"
    naslov3 = "Tajkun (102) onlajn sa prevodom"
    naslov4 = "Tajkun (1990) onlajn sa prevodom"
    print(re.split(expr, naslov1))
    print(re.split(expr, naslov2))
    print(re.split(expr, naslov3))
    print(re.split(expr, naslov4))
```

the output:

```
['Tajkun', '']
['Tajkun', '']
['Tajkun', '']
['Tajkun', '']
```

to get the title, just assign the output of re.split()

```
my_title = re.split(expr, naslov1)[0]
print(my_title)
```

I highly recommend learning regex. Here's a good [tutorial](https://regexone.com/).